# toggle the multiple element(li) except the element clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

There are multiple `li` element in my html code which are collapsible list. I want to toggle all other `li` element except the element clicked on using jQuery.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#boys").on('click', function () {
        $("#hacky").toggle();
        $("#walking1").toggle();
        $("#walking2").toggle();
        $("#walking3").toggle();
    });

    $("#hacky").on('click', function () {
        $("#boys").toggle();
        $("#walking1").toggle();
        $("#walking2").toggle();
        $("#walking3").toggle();
    });

    $("#walking1").on('click', function () {
        $("#boys").toggle();
        $("#hacky").toggle();
        $("#walking2").toggle();
        $("#walking3").toggle();
    });

    $("#walking2").on('click', function () {
        $("#boys").toggle();
        $("#hacky").toggle();
        $("#walking1").toggle();
        $("#walking3").toggle();
    });

    $("#walking3").on('click', function () {
        $("#boys").toggle();
        $("#hacky").toggle();
        $("#walking1").toggle();
        $("#walking2").toggle();
    });
});
```

I've given each `li` element an id and then i'm toggling them.
This isn't the most efficient way of doing it and the code works on static text. The `li` elements can increase or decrease and i want to do this in an efficient way such that even if an element is added in the future i won't have to add an id every time and write the code. I don't know how to use `find()` and `this` tag effieciently and i'm new to jQuery.

Editted:

HTML Code:

```html
<div class="weekday-block">
  <ul class="collapsible roster-collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header active roster-header">
        <h2>Tue 30 June,2015</h2>
      </div>
      <!-- /.collapsible-header -->
      <div class="collapsible-body main-collapsible">
        <ul class="multi-activity-wrapper collapsible-container">
          <li class="collapsible-wrapper" id="boys">
            <ul class="collapsible activity-collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
              <li class="activity-head">
                <div class="collapsible-header roster-header">
                  <h3>Boys's Basketball Meeting</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.collapsible-header -->
                <div class="collapsible-body">
                  <ul class="roster-activity">
                    <li>
                      <h4>Activity</h4>
                      <h3>CLUBS -> Athletic</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4>Room</h4>
                      <h3>425</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4>Capacity</h4>
                      <h3>5/25</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h3>Kevin Schieler</h3>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.collapsible-body -->
                <div class="activity-button-block roster-activity-button-block">
                  <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='javascript:void(0)'" id="button" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" value="Active">
                </div>
                <!-- /.activity-button-block -->
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- /.collapsible-wrapper -->
          <li class="collapsible-wrapper" id="hacky">
            <ul class="collapsible activity-collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
              <li class="activity-head">
                <div class="collapsible-header roster-header">
                  <h3>Hacky Sack Club</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.collapsible-header -->
                <div class="collapsible-body">
                  <ul class="roster-activity">
                    <li>
                      <h4>Activity</h4>
                      <h3>CLUBS -> Athletic</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4>Room</h4>
                      <h3>425</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4>Capacity</h4>
                      <h3>5/25</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h3>Kevin Schieler</h3>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.collapsible-body -->
                <div class="activity-button-block roster-activity-button-block">
                  <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='javascript:void(0)'" id="button" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" value="Set as Active">
                </div>
                <!-- /.activity-button-block -->
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- /.collapsible-wrapper -->
          <li class="collapsible-wrapper" id="walking1">
            <ul class="collapsible activity-collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
              <li class="activity-head">
                <div class="collapsible-header roster-header">
                  <h3>Walking Club</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.collapsible-header -->
                <div class="collapsible-body">
                  <ul class="roster-activity">
                    <li>
                      <h4>Activity</h4>
                      <h3>CLUBS -> Athletic</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4>Room</h4>
                      <h3>425</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4>Capacity</h4>
                      <h3>5/25</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h3>Kevin Schieler</h3>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.collapsible-body -->
                <div class="activity-button-block roster-activity-button-block">
                  <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='javascript:void(0)'" id="button" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" value="Set as Active">
                </div>
                <!-- /.activity-button-block -->
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- /.collapsible-wrapper -->
          <li class="collapsible-wrapper" id="walking2">
            <ul class="collapsible activity-collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
              <li class="activity-head">
                <div class="collapsible-header roster-header">
                  <h3>Walking Club</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.collapsible-header -->
                <div class="collapsible-body">
                  <ul class="roster-activity">
                    <li>
                      <h4>Activity</h4>
                      <h3>CLUBS -> Athletic</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4>Room</h4>
                      <h3>425</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4>Capacity</h4>
                      <h3>5/25</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h3>Kevin Schieler</h3>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.collapsible-body -->
                <div class="activity-button-block roster-activity-button-block">
                  <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='javascript:void(0)'" id="button" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" value="Set as Active">
                </div>
                <!-- /.activity-button-block -->
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- /.collapsible-wrapper -->
          <li class="collapsible-wrapper" id="walking3">
            <ul class="collapsible activity-collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
              <li class="activity-head">
                <div class="collapsible-header roster-header">
                  <h3>Walking Club</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.collapsible-header -->
                <div class="collapsible-body">
                  <ul class="roster-activity">
                    <li>
                      <h4>Activity</h4>
                      <h3>CLUBS -> Athletic</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4>Room</h4>
                      <h3>425</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h4>Capacity</h4>
                      <h3>5/25</h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <h3>Kevin Schieler</h3>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.collapsible-body -->
                <div class="activity-button-block roster-activity-button-block">
                  <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='javascript:void(0)'" id="button" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" value="Set as Active">
                </div>
                <!-- /.activity-button-block -->
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- /.collapsible-wrapper -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.collapsible-body -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /.weekday-block -->
```

Comment: Can you add HTML code also

Comment: `$('#click').on('click', function() { $('li').toggle();$(this).toggle(); });` Something like this?

Comment: well html code is a bit long and most of other things in it are totally irrelevant to what i want to achieve.

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 include **all relevant** code...

Comment: @099 Added the code. I hope you don't get lost there. Thanks. :P

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 We shouldn't, as long as it's relevant (y)

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 You are replying to the comments here, but did you even see the four answers posted?

Comment: @Praveen Just looking at them. Trying to use them in my code now and see which one gives the desired results. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extremly simplify this process by using jquerys' `this`

```
$(".collapsible-wrapper").click(function(){
    $(".collapsible-wrapper").not(this).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
$("li").click(function () {
  $("li").not(this).toggle();
});
```

Or, you can do:

```
$("li").click(function () {
  $("li").toggle();
  $(this).toggle(); // Retoggle
});
```

I have just added the `li` target as an example for this concept. In reality, you need to add a class to use as a selector for the particular `<ul>` element(s) that you want to toggle, otherwise it will toggle all `<li>`'s on the page.

Here is an example of that:

```
$(".myList li").click(function () {
  $(".myList li").not(this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, but you should use `.not()` of `.filter(:not())` instead as it will enabled jQuery to take advantage of the native `document.querySelectorAll()` method

Comment: Oh.. using `this` inside the selector.. I don't think that works

Comment: Excuse me? I don't understand

Comment: @Billy Just targetting the issue, considering there's only LI there. You get it? I would really know the right answer would be adding a class and target that alone. If I should add it, I will do now.

Comment: The OP has only shown the code relevant to the problem. You can't know that there aren't any other `<li>`'s on his page. Or that there never will be. It's just common sense?

Comment: @Billy Agree with you. Check now.

Comment: I have also added an explanation to help the reader understand/learn :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Add a common class to all the `<li>` elements
2. Bind event on the elements using the common class
3. Use `this` context and `siblings()` to get the other elements than the clicked
4. `toggle` the sibling elements
5. I'll also recommend you to use `fadeToggle()` or `slideToggle()` for smooth animation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myLis').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.myLis').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="walking2" class="myLis">1</li>
  <li id="boys" class="myLis">2</li>
  <li id="hacky" class="myLis">3</li>
  <li id="walking1" class="myLis">4</li>
  <li id="walking3" class="myLis">5</li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

*After adding HTML in the question*

You can use following to toggle other `li`s.you can use

```
// On click of the li
$('.collapsible-wrapper').on('click', function () {
    $('.collapsible-wrapper').not(this).slideToggle();
    // toggle li elements other than the clicked
});
```

Comment: This will toggle all including the one that was clicked on.. You need to add `.not(this)`.

Comment: @Billy Kindly check the Section called **EDIT** at the bottom of the answer

Comment: Yes I saw. The main body of your answer is still incorrect.

Comment: @Billy Because the time I answered the question, the HTML was not added by OP in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

HTML:

```
<li onclick="javascript:collapse(this)">test1</li>
```

Script:

```
function collapse(e) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++) 
        if(elem[i]!=e) elem[i].toggle();
}
```

My Example is native JS so .toggle() won't work

Comment: you could do the same in JQuery